Ошибка при работе с библиотекой pygsheets
Программа работает как надо, но почему-то при выполнении данного кода выводится ошибка This range already has a worksheet with different title set.
    import pygsheets
from datetime import datetime


class GoogleTable:
    def __init__(self, credence_service_file: str, googlesheet_file_url: str) -> None:
        self.credence_service_file = credence_service_file
        self.googlesheet_file_url = googlesheet_file_url

 
    def _get_googlesheet_by_url(self):
        try:
            client = self._get_googlesheet_client()
            sheets = client.open_by_url(self.googlesheet_file_url)
            return sheets
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Ошибка подключения к Google Таблице: {e}")

 
    def _get_or_create_sheet(self, sheet_title: str):
        sheets = self._get_googlesheet_by_url()
        normalized_title = sheet_title.strip()

        try:
            # Проверяем существующие листы
            for sheet in sheets.worksheets():
                if sheet.title.strip().lower() == normalized_title.lower():
                    print(f"Лист найден: {sheet.title}")
                    return sheet

            # Если лист не найден, создаем новый
            worksheet = sheets.add_worksheet(normalized_title)
            print(f"Создан новый лист: {normalized_title}")
            return worksheet
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Ошибка при обработке листа: {e}")

 
    def _get_googlesheet_client(self):
        try:
            return pygsheets.authorize(service_file=self.credence_service_file)
        except Exception as e:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Ошибка авторизации Google API: {e}")

 
    def find_admin(self, admin_id: str) -> bool:
        worksheet = self._get_or_create_sheet("Админы")
        worksheet.refresh()

        headers = worksheet.get_row(1)
        if "ID" not in headers:
            return False

        col_index = headers.index("ID") + 1
        all_values = worksheet.get_all_values()

        for row in all_values[1:]:
            if len(row) >= col_index and row[col_index - 1] == admin_id:
                return True
        return False

 
    def add_admin(self, admin_id: str, full_name: str, username: str, phone_number: str) -> None:
        try:
            worksheet = self._get_or_create_sheet("Админы")
            if self.find_admin(admin_id):
                print(f"Админ с ID {admin_id} уже существует.")
                return

            current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M %d.%m.%Y")
            new_row = [full_name, admin_id, username, phone_number, current_time]
            worksheet.append_table(new_row, start="A1", dimension="ROWS", overwrite=False)
            print(f"Добавлен новый админ: {full_name}.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка добавления админа: {e}")
            raise

